# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, es6-promise

I'm trying to retrieve values from mongoDB and its giving me the 
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: topology was destroyed`

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().`

`[DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

Following is the scaled down code version

CLASS 1

```
connectToMongoDatabase() {
    try {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            mongoclient.connect('mongodb://************************', (err, db) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                else {
                    resolve(db);
                }
            });
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}


fetchIssuesFromMongo(dbName, collectionName, query, db) {
    try {
        let dbo = db.db(dbName);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let collection = dbo.collection(collectionName);
            collection.find(query, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                else {
                    resolve(result);
                    dbo.close();
                }
            });
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

CLASS 2

```
executeQuery(issueCount){
   this.CLASS1.connectToMongoDatabase().then((db) => {
       this.CLASS1.fetchIssuesFromMongo(dbName, collectionName, query, db).then((result: any) => {
           expect(result.count()).toEqual(issueCount);
       });
  });
}
```

SPEC FILE

```
it('verify result', (done) => {
    CLASS2.executeQuery(6).then(() => {
         done();
    });    
});
```

What I think is the test fails after  `this.CLASS1.connectToMongoDatabase()`.
Is there any issue with how I'm using promises ? I'm resolving all the promises and have reject statements also in place.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Hey. Just a shot in the dark - when you return Promise I think you need to return something inside of it, in your first case it should be `return mongoclient.connect('mongodb...` and the same for everything inside of other functions

Answer (score 0):

### Updating your Class 1

Remove the try catch since it will never catch on a returned promise. Here's the change for `fetchIssuesFromMongo`. You should do something similar for `connectToMongoDatabase`

```
fetchIssuesFromMongo(dbName, collectionName, query, db) {
  const dbo = db.db(dbName);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const collection = dbo.collection(collectionName);
    collection.find(query, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err); // at this point you should call a .catch
      } else {
        dbo.close();  // switching the order so the close actually happens.
                      // if you want this to close at the exit, you should
                      // probably not do it like this.
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

### Fixing the `executeQuery` in Class 2

In your `executQuery`:

```
executeQuery(issueCount){
  // if connectToMongoDatabase is thenable, then you should also call .catch
  // you should also return a promise here so your Protractor code can actually
  // call .then in `CLASS2.executeQuery(6).then`
  return this.CLASS1.connectToMongoDatabase().then((db) => {
    this.CLASS1.fetchIssuesFromMongo(dbName, collectionName, query, db).then((result: any) => {
      expect(result.count()).toEqual(issueCount);
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  }).catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
  });
}
```

#### Think about using async / await.

This usually helps clear up the nested chain of promises. I prefer this.

```
// this returns implicitly returns a Promise<void>
async executeQuery(issueCount) {
  // valid to use try catch
  try {
    const db = await this.CLASS1.connectToMongoDatabase();
    const result = await this.CLASS1.fetchIssuesFromMongo(dbName, collectionName, query, db);
    expect(result.count()).toEqual(issueCount);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

#### Use async / await in your Protractor test

Finally in your Protractor test you should turn off the selenium promise manager. This is something you'll do in your configuration file. `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,`

Next you can use async / wait in your test.

```
it('verify result', async () => {
    await CLASS2.executeQuery(6);
});
```

I'm not a fan of expecting a condition in your class and it might be better to return the value from class 2. So I would maybe return a Promise from `executeQuery`.

```
const issueCount = 6;
const queryResult = await CLASS2.executeQuery(issueCount);
expect(queryResult).toEqual(issueCount);
```

Hope that helps.